# PVM passing a vector to the slave

Tags: c, vector, pvm

I'm doing a PVM project.
Is it possible to pass a vector to the slave using this command?
Because in my slave I use a vector that counts the % repeated numbers between numbers 1 to 1000. The that vector I want to passed to the master.

```
float *repeated;

int pvm_pkfloat(repeated,1000,,1);
```

Thank You

Comment: Does `float *repeated;` actually point to anything?

Comment: `pvm_pkfloat( float *fp, int nitem, int stride )` takes three arguments, what is your double-comma for?